# Has or Have? Which is grammatically correct and why?

Tags: grammar

Today my friend asked me if you can use **"has"** instead of **"have"** here. I'm not sure how to explain the grammar simply. [image]

⑤"Since there is no other food on the table, and each of them **have** small plates..."

Comment: What strikes me is the use of "since" (as in "since three o'clock") instead of "because."

Answer (score 4):

At least in American English, "each" is treated as singular. Therefore, "has" is preferred, and "have" is non-standard.

> ...each of them **has** a small plate in front of **him**.

This is supported by [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/each), so I suspect it holds true for British English as well:

> When we use each of with a plural noun as subject, it’s normally followed by a singular verb
>   ...
>
> > Each of the buildings **is** surrounded by high metal fencing.
>
> [emphasis added]

Cambridge indicates that in BrE, the use of a plural verb is common in informal speech:

> In informal speaking, you will hear people use a plural verb form:
>
> > A: All twelve of us have decided to go to Argentina together.
> >
> > B: How will you travel around?
> >
> > A: We’ve divided ourselves into three groups and each of the groups **have** hired a car.

In my experience, this is not common usage from American speakers.

Comment: Note: I don't find the Cambridge example of plural verb usage very enlightening, because a British English speaker might use a plural verb form with a group noun like *team* or *group* anyway.

Comment: Would "each group have hired a car" work in British English?

Comment: @sumelic, As I understand it, it would. So would "The team have won the championship" (with no complication due to using "each"). But I don't speak BrE, so don't trust me too far on this one.

Answer (score -1):

English verbs in present tense have a different form for the third person singular that ends in *s* for all verbs except *to be* which has more forms.

*Has* is that form for *have*.

> I have X, you have X, he/she/it *has* X, we have X, they have X.

*Each* is a plural pronoun.  You only use it when referring to a group of things.  So you don't use the third person singular form a of a verb with it.

*Each one* is not a plural pronoun, though.

> Since there is no other food on the table, and each one of them has small plates.

Of course in casual conversation you will probably hear the opposite a lot and a lot of speakers will barely notice it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! 
I'm still a little bit confused though...does that mean "have" would be grammatically correct here, but usually we would use "has" in casual conversation?

Comment: "Has" is wrong but you will still hear people say it.  You should always say "have."

Comment: I don't know grammar, but in COCA, "each of them has" has a frequency of 72  while "each of them have" has a frequency of 20 only. And also, see this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+of+them+has%2C+each+of+them+have&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ceach%20of%20them%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Beach%20of%20them%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEach%20of%20them%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ceach%20of%20them%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Beach%20of%20them%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEach%20of%20them%20have%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Cambridge seems to disagree with you about which verb form is used with *each*. See my answer.

Comment: Checking [*each of which **has/have***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+of+which+has%2Ceach+of+which+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceach%20of%20which%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceach%20of%20which%20have%3B%2Cc0) in Google NGrams it's immediately obvious that the plural verb usage is quite uncommon on both sides of the pond. But comparing AmE/BrE corpuses suggests ***Brits*** are slightly more flexible on this one...

Comment: ...my guess is that's because of contexts like *There are three families involved in the legal action, each of which **have** their own lawyer*. As a Brit, I'm fine with something like a *family* being singular or plural according to context, and that *specific* cited context doesn't seem particularly "marked" to me (I'm certainly fine with *My/his family have our/their own lawyer*, whatever Americans may think about that).

Comment: Looking at some of the ngram examples for *have*, only a few of them are relevant. Sometimes *have* is an infinitive, sometimes it does not refer to *each*.

Comment: You're agreeing backwards with their, but it should be its. A family is a thing.